# Can't upload a PNG file with OKHttp - File Not Found

Tags: android, okhttp

I am having trouble uploading an image to a Restful service, using the Multipart upload.
I am using a Recipe from the OKHttp Examples.

For some reason, the upload doesn't find the image.

I validate the file is valid (I can output info about the file, and see that it is found), but when the upload is supposed to happen, I get an error that tells me the file is not found.

Can anybody see what am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap bmp = attachment.getBitmap(getActivity(), ATTACHMENT_IMG_SIZE);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);
            File file = new File(attachment.getFilename(getActivity()));
            try {
                Log.d("MSW", "The file Canonical Path: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                Log.d("MSW", "The file name: " + file.getName());
                Log.d("MSW", "The file Path: " + file.getPath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            client.networkInterceptors().add(loggingInterceptor);

            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                    .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                    .addFormDataPart("method_name", "upload_attach")
                    .addFormDataPart("forum_id", getArguments().getString(ARG_FORUM_ID))
                    .addFormDataPart("attachment[]", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/png"), file))
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(AppConfig.MOBIQUO_ATTACH_URL)
                    .post(requestBody)
                    .build();

            String respStr = "";
            Log.d("MSW", "BEFORE ---: ");
            try {
                Log.d("MSW", "BEFORE RESP: ");
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("MSW", "Response UNSuccessful: ");
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                    Log.d("MSW", "Response Successful: " + response.body().string());
                    respStr = response.body().string();
                    System.out.println(response.body().string());
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("MSW", "Exception: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("MSW", "Response is: " + respStr);
            return parseResponse(respStr);
        }
```

Here is the error message:

```
        11-23 16:03:17.525  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ The file Canonical Path: /4970.jpg
    11-23 16:03:17.525  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ The file name: 4970.jpg
    11-23 16:03:17.525  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ The file Path: 4970.jpg
    11-23 16:03:17.618  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ BEFORE ---:
    11-23 16:03:17.618  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ BEFORE RESP:
    11-23 16:03:17.763  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ --> POST /mobiquo/upload.php HTTP/1.1
    11-23 16:03:17.763  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=46df9530-8ac4-4943-a980-fc61b4879002
    11-23 16:03:17.763  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Length: 449
    11-23 16:03:17.763  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Host: forums.androidcentral.com
    11-23 16:03:17.763  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Connection: Keep-Alive
    11-23 16:03:17.764  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Accept-Encoding: gzip
    11-23 16:03:17.764  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Cookie: acsessionhash=6cddfd7c1fe76a344309c9dfac7dfac0; PassportLocalSession=6e64cce2-7e01-4a2d-803e-dc9d1636704c-54c6048c-5152-4419-884f-d1301e7baf5f; acpassword=ae7da81dda3b79580a2351049281767f; PassportSessionDate=1448323386; acuserid=2669245; SESSf659a72bed167194167ec3641e600b60=9ct3V89eQufYoRYvRpIVEWg5R69E4GqVzQD7x3B2n0o; PassportSession=6e64cce2-7e01-4a2d-803e-dc9d1636704c-54c6048c-5152-4419-884f-d1301e7baf5f
    11-23 16:03:17.764  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ User-Agent: okhttp/2.6.0
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ --> POST /mobiquo/upload.php HTTP/1.1
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=46df9530-8ac4-4943-a980-fc61b4879002
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Content-Length: 449
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Host: forums.androidcentral.com
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Connection: Keep-Alive
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Accept-Encoding: gzip
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ Cookie: acsessionhash=6cddfd7c1fe76a344309c9dfac7dfac0; PassportLocalSession=6e64cce2-7e01-4a2d-803e-dc9d1636704c-54c6048c-5152-4419-884f-d1301e7baf5f; acpassword=ae7da81dda3b79580a2351049281767f; PassportSessionDate=1448323386; acuserid=2669245; SESSf659a72bed167194167ec3641e600b60=9ct3V89eQufYoRYvRpIVEWg5R69E4GqVzQD7x3B2n0o; PassportSession=6e64cce2-7e01-4a2d-803e-dc9d1636704c-54c6048c-5152-4419-884f-d1301e7baf5f
    11-23 16:03:17.819  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/OkHttp﹕ User-Agent: okhttp/2.6.0
    11-23 16:03:17.820  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 4970.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    11-23 16:03:17.820  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: 4970.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    11-23 16:03:17.826  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:163)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:117)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBuilder.java:277)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.writeTo(MultipartBuilder.java:297)
    11-23 16:03:17.827  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:163)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:867)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:748)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:277)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:234)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:196)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.androidcentral.app.fragments.AttachmentListFragment$UploadAttachmentTask.doInBackground(AttachmentListFragment.java:269)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at com.androidcentral.app.fragments.AttachmentListFragment$UploadAttachmentTask.doInBackground(AttachmentListFragment.java:220)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    11-23 16:03:17.828  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    11-23 16:03:17.829  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
    11-23 16:03:17.829  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
    11-23 16:03:17.829  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
    11-23 16:03:17.829  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app W/System.err﹕ ... 20 more
    11-23 16:03:17.829  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app D/MSW﹕ Response is:
    11-23 16:03:17.832  27377-27956/com.androidcentral.app E/AttachmentListFragment﹕ org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.StringReader@24f2e54a)
                at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2054)
                at com.androidcentral.app.fragments.AttachmentListFragment$UploadAttachmentTask.parseResponse(AttachmentListFragment.java:296)
                at com.androidcentral.app.fragments.AttachmentListFragment$UploadAttachmentTask.doInBackground(AttachmentListFragment.java:285)
                at com.androidcentral.app.fragments.AttachmentListFragment$UploadAttachmentTask.doInBackground(AttachmentListFragment.java:220)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1):

The file doesn’t exist. You can confirm this by reading its first byte with a FileInputStream.

Comment: or calling the .exists() method - but the file in question can't exist.

Answer (score 1):

> The file Canonical Path: /4970.jpg

This is an impossible file path for any normal Android device, as the root directory is not only never writable but apps, but generally speaking is a read-only filesystem.

This indicates that your function is being called with an invalid argument, an issue which you need to fix in the caller.

Comment: I was able to resolve the missing file (I was incorrectly creating the Byte array to upload).  Thanks again, I am please this is working (and this was helpful to know that the file was incorrect, and not the format of the call I was making)